# Multiple Check box in edit mode: Undefined index

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have multiple checkbox in a form, such as:

1. Car
2. Bike
3. Plane
4. Boat
5. Walk

User can choose one, two, three, or all of it. At the first time, I tried to choosed just one or two option, when I processed the script there's error statement -> "*Undefined index for car*", "*Undefined index for boat*" for option I didn't checked. So I was googled and found the answer with this script: (*For the insert script*)

```
$car   =  (isset($_POST['car']))?$_POST['car']:NULL;
$bike  =  (isset($_POST['bike']))?$_POST['bike']:NULL;
$plane =  (isset($_POST['plane']))?$_POST['plane']:NULL;
$boat  =  (isset($_POST['boat']))?$_POST['boat']:NULL;
$walk  =  (isset($_POST['walk']))?$_POST['walk']:NULL;
```

and it was worked perfectly, but then when I want to update my form with this script: (*Update/Edit Form*)

```
    if(isset($_POST['save'])) {

    include('connection.php');

    $car   =  (isset($_POST['car']))?$_POST['car']:NULL;
    $bike  =  (isset($_POST['bike']))?$_POST['bike']:NULL;
    $plane =  (isset($_POST['plane']))?$_POST['plane']:NULL;
    $boat  =  (isset($_POST['boat']))?$_POST['boat']:NULL;
    $walk  =  (isset($_POST['walk']))?$_POST['walk']:NULL;

$update = mysql_query("UPDATE information SET(
car   = (isset($_POST['car']))?$_POST['car']:NULL; 
bike  = (isset($_POST['bike']))?$_POST['bike']:NULL;
plane = (isset($_POST['plane']))?$_POST['plane']:NULL;
boat  = (isset($_POST['boat']))?$_POST['boat']:NULL;
walk  = (isset($_POST['walk']))?$_POST['walk']:NULL;
)")
```

and there's an error, with the quotation marked, so I've changed it into this script: (Fixing the quotation marked)

```
    if(isset('$_POST[save]')) {

    include('connection.php');

    $car   =  (isset('$_POST[car]'))?'$_POST[car]':NULL;
    $bike  =  (isset('$_POST[bike]'))?'$_POST[bike]':NULL;
    $plane =  (isset('$_POST[plane]'))?'$_POST[plane]':NULL;
    $boat  =  (isset('$_POST[boat]'))?'$_POST[boat]':NULL;
    $walk  =  (isset('$_POST[walk]'))?'$_POST[walk]':NULL;

    $update = mysql_query("UPDATE information SET(
    car   = (isset('$_POST[car]'))?'$_POST[car]':NULL; 
    bike  = (isset('$_POST[bike]'))?'$_POST[bike]':NULL;
    plane = (isset('$_POST[plane]'))?'$_POST[plane]':NULL;
    boat  = (isset('$_POST[boat]'))?'$_POST[boat]':NULL;
    walk  = (isset('$_POST[walk]'))?'$_POST[walk]':NULL;
    )")

if($update){

echo 'Update Success! ';        
echo '<a href="index.php">Results</a>'; 
    }else{

echo 'Failed To Update! ';      
echo '<a href="index.php">Home</a>';    

    }

}else{  

echo '<script>window.history.back()</script>';
```

Still got error's "*Undefined index*" but then I was found a solution from stackoverflow also, like this:

```
function checkbox_value($name) {
    return (isset($_POST[$name]) ? 1 : 0);
}

$sql =  'UPDATE table SET '.
        'checkbox1 = '. checkbox_value('checkbox1') .','.
        'checkbox2 = '. checkbox_value('checkbox2') .','.
        'checkbox3 = '. checkbox_value('checkbox3') .','.
        'checkbox4 = '. checkbox_value('checkbox4') .','.
        'checkbox5 = '. checkbox_value('checkbox5') .','. "LIMIT 1";
```

I've made changes into this/like this:

```
function checkbox_value($update) {
    return (isset($_POST[$update]) ? 1 : 0);
}

$update =  'UPDATE information SET '.
        'car = '. checkbox_value('car') .','.
        'bike = '. checkbox_value('bike') .','.
        'plane = '. checkbox_value('plane') .','.
        'boat = '. checkbox_value('boat') .','.
        'walk = '. checkbox_value('walk') .','. "LIMIT 1";
```

The "*Undefined index*" was gone, but Failed to update the data. Little bit confusing here...anyone can give me a suggestion please. Thank you very much for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Your original code was vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

And your `checkbox_value()` version has syntax errors:

```
    'walk = '. checkbox_value('walk') .','. "LIMIT 1";
                                       ^^^^
```

This would produce the sql snippet

```
  walk = 1,LIMIT 1
          ^---
```

which is invalid. And if you fix this, note that it has no `WHERE` clause: you'd be updating only the FIRST record in this table, which may not be what you want.

Since you didn't mention getting any errors from the DB because of that error, you probably don't have any error checking at all. At bare minimum, you should have something like

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Never assume a DB operation will succeed. Always assume value, check for that failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.